# SSH Problems when trying to connect

Tags: macos, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to connect via ssh to my pi on my mac and frankly I don't know much about what I am doing. I just reformatted my pi 2b with the latest version a raspbain and got this  error message : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOrUX.png) can any one help. Thanks so much. :) -Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the file /Users/YOU/.ssh/known_hosts and remove the ip and key of the pi